# Is The include Command of PHP buffered?

Tags: php, include

I've some problems in my script with inlcuding some Files with `include`

I can reduce it to a small code example:

```
<?php

$res = 0;
include "test.txt";
echo "RES = > $res".PHP_EOL;

file_put_contents('./test.txt','<?php $res='.($res+1).';'.PHP_EOL);

include "test.txt";
echo "RES = > $res".PHP_EOL;
```

I'm expecting an Output of

```
  RES => 0
  RES => 1
  //On next Call I'm expecting ...
  RES => 1
  RES => 2
```

But what I'm getting:

```
  RES => 0
  RES => 0
```

Even the next call gives the same Result (RES => 0). When I recall the Script 1-2 sec later, I'm getting an increment of the RES.

So my question: Is the include statement of PHP buffered? I haven't seen some parts in the documentation of php about buffering. What is the problem with my example?

Comment: I'm working with a standard php/apache installation under ubuntu (v2.4.18/7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3)

Comment: You code is working fine for me. Make sure `www-data` user has **write** permissions under this path. Also turn on displaying errors in php.ini to get more information about your problems in the future.

Comment: I can't replicate.

Comment: Is APC or other such *caches* active?

Comment: I get no message in the apache error log (except for the first call, when no test.txt exist).And yes.. php can write to the folder.

Comment: Yes OPCcache is enable and running:

Comment: Disable OPCache and try it. Also try from the command line. For me it's working from the command line.

Comment: Also, do you have a link to a phpinfo output for your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running the example from the command line or with disabled opcache, the script works fine.

Disabling opcache would give correct results.
A workaround with an enabled opcache would be something like this (this will prevent caching the file):

```
//Instead of include "test.txt";
//we include the part manual by eval
$cont = file_get_contents("test.txt");
//Strip of leading <?php and eval the string
eval(substr($cont, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether or not you have an OPCode cache installed. If you do the script is loaded from memory after the first time.

I'm not sure on the behavior without an OPCode cache. PHP may load the file from disk each time you call `include`. You could find out with [strace](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) et al. You'll probably reap the benefits of a filesystem cache even if PHP is going back to disk on subsequent invocations of `include`.

Generally I would encourage use of an OPCode cache.

**EDIT**

I now see you're changing the content of the file before the second `include`... I've tried your example from the CLI and it's working as you expect. Try it on your server via the CLI. If it works (which it should) then there's a good chance you have an OPCode cache enabled and the particular configuration is preventing the expected behavior.

You should also verify Apache is writing out the updated file as you expect. Maybe when you write to disk with `file_put_contents`, you also *log* what each version of the generated file is. Something like this after your existing `file_put_contents` call:

```
// For logging
file_put_contents('./test-' . time() . '.txt','<?php $res='.($res+1).';'.PHP_EOL);
```